# How can I set a type of an Array so it is a keyof an interface?

Tags: typescript

This is quite hard for me to explain, as I'm not sure what to call it. I have a interface and I want to set some properties using an array element as such:

```
interface MyStuff {
  key?: boolean;
};

var myThing: MyStuff = {};

var MyStuffArray: /* magic code */ = [];

MyStuffArray.push("key");

for(var p of MyStuffArray) {
  myThing[p /* magic code */] = true;
};
```

magic code being the area where I don't know what to put it as; because MyStuffArray can be only filled with keys from `MyStuff`.

I have tried `myThing[p as keyof MyStuff] = true;` but I get an error: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

This works: `(myThing as any)[p] = true`, however I feel like this is bad practice when you have to use the `any` keyword in any situation.

If it helps: I do not want `MyStuffArray` to be filled with keys of `MyStuff`! I just want it so `MyStuffArray` *can* be filled with possible keys of `MyStuff`.

Comment: Is the array allowed to have multiple keys of the same value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `keyof` operator for the array declaration, and test for the property before doing an assignation, like this:

```
interface MyStuff {
    key?: boolean;
    other?: string;
};

var myThing: MyStuff = {};

var MyStuffArray: (keyof MyStuff)[] = [];

MyStuffArray.push('key');

for (var p of MyStuffArray) {
    if (p === 'key') {
        myThing[p] = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (and preferable is to just use `keyof` keyword
However, If you'd like to achieve even more type safety you could go ahead with the following code. It will keep you from pushing the same key to the array twice.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends never ? never : (arg: U) => never
) extends (arg: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type UnionToTuple<T> = UnionToIntersection<
  T extends never ? never : (t: T) => T
> extends (_: never) => infer W
  ? [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, W>>, W]
  : [];

//////////////////////////
//////// your code ///////

interface MyStuff {
  key?: boolean;
};

var myThing: MyStuff = {};

// Only one element 'key' is possible in the array
var myStuffArray: UnionToTuple<keyof MyStuff> = ['key'];

for(var p of myStuffArray) {
  myThing[p /* magic code */] = true;
};
```